# Как удалить иероглифы из календаря?

Tags: windows

Сегодня обнаружил, что календарь выглядит вот так:
[image: Календарь с иероглифами]

Хотя вчера был нормальный (но это не точно). 
Как это можно подправить, а то у меня что-то нет идей. В региональных настройках все норм.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это японские кандзи. Странно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел. *Настройки* → *Время и язык* → *Показывать дополнительные календари на панели задач* устанавливаем значение «*Не показывать дополнительные календари*». 
[Видео на Ютубе с демонстрацией](https://youtu.be/2bebb_Kxvpg)

Comment: Спасибо, Nikolay Petyukh
У меня тоже win 10 после обновления в апреле начало показывать иероглифы в календарях Параметры - Настройки → Время и язык → Показывать дополнительные календари

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо создать текстовый файл. В него скопировать:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage]
"1251"="c_1251.nls"
"1252"="c_1251.nls"
"1253"="c_1251.nls"
"1254"="c_1251.nls"
"1255"="c_1251.nls"
```

Затем сохранить файл с разрешением .reg и запустить его. После этого выполнить перезагрузку.

[Ответ на answers.microsoft.com](https://answers.microsoft.com/ru-ru/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_repair/%D0%B8%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%84/01ea7d1d-6703-40e2-ba6d-3393f8f3adf9)

Comment: У меня английский язык интерфейса, региональные настройки тоже, и локаль английская. Именно 1251 там нужна?

Comment: Не помогло, все равно иероглифы